# get geometry Data of a loaded qmesh (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d, qt5.8

my Problem: i load a 3D-Model into a QMesh:

```
Qt3DRender::QMesh *mesh;
mesh->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/new/prefix1/ata.obj")));
```

This works at the moment.

Now I search a function that gives me the geometry data of the Object,      particularly: midpoint, corner

In the end I want to transform my loaded 3D Model to the viewpoint of my camera.

I use qt 5.8. Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: From Qt documentation :
mesh->geometry() holds the geometry data.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt Documentation :

QMesh is a specialization of Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer, which provides geometry() to give access to geometry data (Qt3DRender::QGeometry).

There you have several options to access your data, look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qgeometry.html#attributes

and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qattribute.html#details for details.